# Changing color of one part of an image using selective palette

Tags: css, svg

So I'm trying to figure out how to select one part of a JPG/SVG image (I'm using SVG) and put a selective palette to change each part with a different color, I searched but I couldn't find any helpful solution... I have couple of SVG images and I need an example, at least a palette template. Question is:

1. How to select 1 part of an image
2. How to change color of one by one part of an image

I need to use a palette for a user who could change color of any part of an image as he wants.

This is an example
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple example of how you can select a colour and use it to change the colour of an SVG element.  The code should be pretty simple to follow.

```js
let currentSelectedColour = "red";

// For each palette button...
document.querySelectorAll(".palette button").forEach(btn => {
  // ... add a click handler that sets the current palette colour
  btn.addEventListener("click", evt => {
    // 'dataset.colour' is the value of the data-colour attribute.
    currentSelectedColour = evt.target.dataset.colour;
    // Update the "Current colour is" field to show this colour name
    document.getElementById("selectedColour").textContent = currentSelectedColour;
  });
});

// For each element in the SVG...
document.querySelectorAll("circle, rect").forEach(shape => {
  // ... add a click handler that sets the fill to  the current selected colour
  shape.addEventListener("click", evt => {
    evt.target.setAttribute("fill", currentSelectedColour);
  });
});
```

```css
svg circle,
svg rect {
   stroke: black;
}

div {
  margin: 3em 0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" viewBox="0 0 400 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="linen"/>
  <rect x="110" y="10" width="80" height="80" fill="linen"/>
  <circle cx="250" cy="50" r="45" fill="linen"/>
  <rect x="310" y="10" width="80" height="80" fill="linen"/>
</svg>

<div class="palette">
  <button type="button" data-colour="red">Red</button>
  <button type="button" data-colour="orange">Orange</button>
  <button type="button" data-colour="yellow">Yellow</button>
  <button type="button" data-colour="green">Green</button>
  <button type="button" data-colour="blue">Blue</button>
  <button type="button" data-colour="violet">Violet</button>
</div>

<div>
  Current colour is: <span id="selectedColour">red</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very helpful! But I updated my post and I want to paint something like this. Can you help me with it?

Comment: As long as your image is an SVG, my code should work.  By SVG, I mean that it consists of vector shapes like rectangles and `<path>` elements.  If you need it to work with a bitmap image, like a PNG or JPEG, you would probably have to have a solution based on the Canvas API.